# Add new child to existing child

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

So I have this kind of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <Project1>
 <Students>
   <Student>
     <name>test2</name>
     <studentnum>01</studentnum>
   </Student>
 </Students>
</Project1>
</root>
```

To add a new Student to this XML file, I use this code (C#)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("datastorage.xml"));
XmlElement Student = doc.CreateElement("Student");

XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("name");
XmlText xmlName = doc.CreateTextNode(txtStudentName1.Text);

XmlElement studentnum = doc.CreateElement("studentnum");
XmlText xmlStudentnum = doc.CreateTextNode(txtStudentNum1.Text);

name.AppendChild(xmlName);
studentnum.AppendChild(xmlStudentnum);

Student.AppendChild(name);
Student.AppendChild(studentnum);

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Student);

doc.Save(Server.MapPath("datastorage.xml"));
```

But the problem is, it adds a new Student to the Root, not to the Project1/Students parant.
How do I do this?

I've seen solutions with XmlTextWriter, but that is not included anymore in 4.5...

Comment: `XmlTextWriter` is still in .NET 4.5, but you should use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead of `new XmlTextWriter()`. Also, LINQ to XML is much easier in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find using Linq To Xml easier

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
xDoc.Descendants("Project1").Descendants("Students")
    .First()
    .Add(new XElement("Student", 
                new XElement("name","test3"),
                new XElement("studentnum","03")));

xDoc.Save(filename);
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Project1>
    <Students>
      <Student>
        <name>test2</name>
        <studentnum>01</studentnum>
      </Student>
      <Student>
        <name>test3</name>
        <studentnum>03</studentnum>
      </Student>
    </Students>
  </Project1>
</root>
```

Comment: Thankyou, to better suit my example, I have edited your answer a little, because I have a `<Project1>` Element above it, later I will have more Projects in this XML file, so I can make sure it places the Student in the correct Project

Comment: @RageCompex Then I would write it as `xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Project1/Students").Add(.....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlNode studentsNode= doc.SelectSingleNode("Project1/Students");

studentsNode.AppendChild(Student);
```